# How do you 'check' a checkbox using scrapy's FormRequest?

Tags: python, forms, scrapy

I am working with the form found at https://www.fbo.gov/index?s=opportunity&tab=search&mode=list.

I need to scrape the results given by checking one or more checkboxes in that group on the form. From my understanding, just giving a checkbox element the 'checked' attribute represents a checked box. How do I define that in my FormRequest?

This is the input element I am testing with

```
<div 
    id="div_dnf_class_values_procurement_notice__naics_code___0001_check"
>
    <input 
        name="dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][naics_code][]" 
        type="checkbox" 
        value="0001"
        id="dnf_class_values_procurement_notice__naics_code___0001_check" 
        class="input-checkbox"
    >
    <label 
        for="dnf_class_values_procurement_notice__naics_code___0001_check"
    >
        111 -- Crop Production
    </label>
</div>
```

The form uses a POST method. This is my current code:

```
import scrapy


class ContractsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "contracts"

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.fbo.gov/index?s=opportunity&tab=search&mode=list'

        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)


    def parse(self, response):
            yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][naics_code][]' : '0001',
                      'dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][searchtype]' : 'active',
                      'dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][all_agencies]' : 'all',
                      'dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][recovery_act]' : '0'},
            formname='vendor_procurement_notice_search',
            callback=self.after_form,
            method="POST",
        )

    def after_form(self, response):
        filename = 'response.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
        return response
```

I am new to scrapy and very confused about what my formdata attribute should consist of? The extra elements in the dict are just required field radioboxes in the form. Not sure if they're necessary to add here. The FormRequest documentation from scrapy is pretty bare, I'm having a lot of trouble.

I followed the advice of one of the answers below and use the name of the input element, but there are a lot of input elements with that name. Plus, how would I go about checking multiple checkboxes in one submission?

I want the after_form function to write the results html to a file just so I know it works.

Answer (score 0):

To send the form with checkbox checked, your form data should contain this key-value pair: `'dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][naics_code][]': '0001'`, which is the name-value of the input element (checkbox).

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but it has that value while unchecked (when the page is loaded). Also, all of the other checkbox inputs have different values. Is each one unique? Also the names of all of those input checkboxes is the same as this one. I will try this regardless, thank you!

Comment: It did not work, please check out my edits to the question details